# Getting required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'Scenario:' in Karate cucumber

Tags: selenium, cucumber, karate

Hello I am new to Karate framework and was trying basic pgm.I get error near scenario : required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'Scenario
If I remove background error disappears.

Below is my basic pgm

```
Feature: Get all the countries
Background: 
*url 'https://restcountries.eu'
Scenario: get the countries
Given path 'rest/v2/all'
When method GET
Then status 200
Then print response
```

I have used below version in pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intuit.karate/karate-apache -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
<artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
<version>0.9.5</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intuit.karate/karate-junit4 -->
<dependency>
<groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
<artifactId>karate-junit4</artifactId>
<version>0.9.5</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But If I close and re-open eclipse, this error is no longer displaying. And again whenever I do any change, this keeps coming back.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bug in the Eclipse plugin. Use Visual Studio Code or IntelliJ and see if you see the same problem: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/IDE-Support

Else can be a bug. Please follow this process in that case: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue